# How to show user's location with blue dot in other place of Mapkit?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, xcode8

I'm a newcomer of swift 3 & Xcode 8, and this is my first time to ask question here. I want to set several pins in a Mapkit, and I also want to add user's location in the same Mapkit simultaneously. Furthermore, I hoped that the center of this Mapkit is a specific location instead of user's location. However, I faced a problem.

I could set those pins in my Mapkit successfully, but I could not show user's location in the same Mapkit. If I try to set user's location as the center of this Mapkit, I could show user's location successfully. My codes was shown below.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!

let manager = CLLocationManager()

func createSpanAndAnnotation() {
    let FirstSpan: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.008, 0.008)
    let originalLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 24.942653, longitude: 121.368598)
    let EdittedRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: originalLocation, span: FirstSpan)
    MapView.setRegion(EdittedRegion, animated: true)

    let TemporaryGarbageCanLatitude = showData().garbageCanLatitudeArray
    let TemporaryGarbageCanLongtitude = showData().garbageCanLontitudeArray
    let TemporaryGarbageCanDiscription = showData().garbageCanDiscription
// 'showdata' is another class to store my data of garbageCans in another file.

    for i in 0...TemporaryGarbageCanLatitude.count-1 {
    let garbageCanLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: TemporaryGarbageCanLatitude[i], longitude: TemporaryGarbageCanLongtitude[i])
    let pin = PinAnnotation(title: "Free Garbage Can", subtitle: TemporaryGarbageCanDiscription[i], coordinate: garbageCanLocation)
    MapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    }   
}

//-------------------------------------<Above code could work successfully>-------------------------------------
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    self.MapView.showsUserLocation = true
}

func locationManager2() {
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
//--------------------------------<It seems that Above code could not work successfully>--------------------------------

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createSpanAndAnnotation()
    locationManager2()  
 }
}
```

I have added 'CoreLocation.framework' in Build Phases, and I also have added 'Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description' in info.plist file. I also turned on the location services in setting when I ran the simulator. Additionally, I didn't live in USA, so I even went to 'simulator > Debug > Location > Custom location' to change my location to where I stay now.

However, I still couldn't not show user's location successfully after I finished all of the things above. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? I would appreciate it if anyone could help me, thanks!

(My screen shot of my Mapkit is here, but I blurred some confidential information on it.)
[simulator screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62VVj.png)

Comment: You do not need a location manager for MapKit. Just tell it to show user location and it will automatically request it for you.. Then check `isUserLocationVisible` to see if it's actually there.. then check the user location from the mapView.userLocation to see the coordinates. You can also set userTrackingMode if you want to constantly track the user.

Comment: You still need to use a `CLLocationManager` at some point to request access to the user's location, though

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for your instruction. I would try those those things later.

Comment: @MichaelHulet Thanks for your instruction. I would memorize it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I solved my problem unexpectedly by changing my custom location in simulator. I lived in east hemisphere, so it seems that the longitude of the place I stayed is positive. However, I typed my longitude as negative value originally. When I changed my longitude to a positive value, my location was shown on the Mapkit successfully.

Thanks for every genius who helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: You should accept your answer by clicking the green check mark to indicate that it resolved your problem.